# Scanning receipts into a spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr

I've been getting more strict with my budget and tracking my spending lately and I want to create an itemized spending tracker in a spreadsheet.

i.e. instead of putting in a $50 grocery store receipt, I'd like to put in a $2 egg receipt and a $3 milk receipt, etc.

This way I can more accurately budget and not include, for example, non-grocery items on a trip to the grocery store.

I did a quick Google search and found the "pytesseract" library and of course the PIL library. And after a quick tutorial I got the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

# Set the path to the Tesseract executable (update this with your path)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/opt/homebrew/bin/tesseract'

# Open an image using Pillow (PIL)
image = Image.open('reciepts/2023_09_04/IMG_0001.tif')

# Use pytesseract to extract text from the image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

# Print the extracted text
print(text)
```

[image: This is a lower resolution scan of an example receipt]

This is the resulting text extraction:

> Blockquote

Wendy s Restaurant #00011710
FC112 1 Camp LeJeune
Camp LeJeune, NC 28547

Host: Saniyah
Cashier: Zenaida

#3072

REPRINT# 1
Order Type:

LARGE COMBO

Son Baconator

Large Fries

LG Sweet Tea
6 Piece Nuggets

Ranch Dipping Sauce

(910) 451-3966
#30 /72

PUW

N-FREE-6PC-NUGGETS

Tax

Total Items 4

PUW Total

Debit #XXXXXXXXXXXX4275
Auth:805301

Sitentdy 14410

App Label:

EMV AID:

Entry Method:
Auth Mode:

CVM;

09/02/2023

2:24 PM
40075

10.19

10.90
$10.90

Term #: 4

US DEBIT
A0000000980840
Chip

Issuer
NoCvmRequired

Flip the burger to save

/
(

)

MM

_/MNMMMMMMMMMMMI

}

:MMMMMMMMMMMMM_/MMM :

\

/

--- Check Closed ---

> Blockquote

It works for the most part but is not ideal. It leaves out some data and improperly formats the rest. After a break, I figured someone else has probably had the same idea before about tracking receipts and thought I'd ask some smart people.

If you can help I sure would appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe try using `--psm 4` for the `config` argument?